# PHP in_array not working correctly

Tags: php

I am creating this array from a posted textarea and splitting the lines:

```
$ignored = array();
foreach(explode("\n", $_POST["ignored"]) as $ignored2) {
    $ignored[] = $ignored2;
    echo $ignored2.'<br>';
}
```

then i have a while loop where i check if any of the array items are in a variable within the while loop:

```
while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    //check if the description is anything in the ignore array
    if(in_array($data[6], $ignored)) {
        echo 'ignore';
    } else {
        echo 'dont ignore';
    }
}
```

I put the following in the textarea (one on each line):

```
SIP Trunk: ST17830T001 (200 channels)
SIP Trunk: ST17830T002 (1 channels)
```

but its only echoing 'ignore' once and its not ignoring the other item (they both exist in the $data[6] variable

Comment: FYI, your `foreach` loop can be replaced with just `$ignored = explode(...)`.

Comment: whitespaces? have you tried trimming both array elements? http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: Can you show the contents of the CSV file?

Comment: Does it even enter the while loop?

Comment: its not creating the array correctly.. if i remove the foreach loop and use this for the array: $ignored = array('SIP Trunk: ST17830T001 (200 channels)','SIP Trunk: ST17830T002 (1 channels)'); it works fine. how can i create the array as it should be ?

Comment: As @rlatief said, the problem is probably that there's extra whitespace in the textarea. You need to trim it before putting the lines into the array.

Comment: Just as an extra: you should use the strict parameter of in_array to be sure that php does no type magic. It is the third parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trim the data from the textarea:

```
$ignored = array();
foreach(explode("\n", $_POST["ignored"]) as $ignored2) {
    $ignored[] = trim($ignored2);
    echo $ignored2.'<br>';
}
```

Also trim the variable you're testing:

```
if (in_array(trim($data[6]), $ignored)) {
```

Comment: trim fixed the very issue I was having.